# gVim how to avoid automatic line creation when editing txt file

Tags: vim

In my _gvimrc file I have set :

set wrap

set textwidth=0 wrapmargin=0

The problem is that when I edit a *.txt file, gVim keeps to create a new line when I reach the 80 column.

To avoid this I went in menu Edit -> File Settings -> Text Width
and I set "0" instead of the "78" that was written. 
In this way the problem disappears but only for the current session. When I close and reopen gVim, Edit -> File Settings -> Text Width  -> "78" again, my "0" settings has disappears.

How can I avoid this automatic line creation, or how can I set permanently Text Width 0 in gVim?

Comment: I think I have found the solution [ I copy here an extract from http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatic_word_wrapping ]   set formatoptions+=t
will automatically wrap text as close to 79 characters as white space allows without exceeding the 79 character limit.   Therefore by setting set formatoptions-=t in _gvimrc the problem disappears and it does not create anymore a new line

Answer (score 1):

Add in your _gvimrc file:
set formatoptions-=t